# How to install a Python package via setup.py which depends on C binaries that may not be installable on the user machine

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I hope I am explaining the problem correctly in the title but this is my situation:

At our workplace, we do not have admin access on our laptops, but I need to use a Python library which uses C binaries. When I try to install the package via pip, it fails due to not being able to install the binaries or find them anywhere. I got around this by downloading the .whl file and installing it manually.

Now I am trying to package my application so it can be installed from pip (from our internal Gitlab server). When you try this, it obviously fails for the same reason as why you can't just install it via pip in the first place.

I am trying to find a way for my setup.py to detect if it fails, and if so to simply go to the URL where I found the .whl and install it manually. Is this a bad idea? If not, how can I do it? I tried wrapping the call to `setup()` in a try block so I could see if it threw an exception but it doesn't seem to show anything:

```
# package requires
with open(os.path.join(here, "requirements.txt")) as f:
    install_requires = f.readlines()

# setup config
try:
    setup(
        name=about['__title__'],
        version=about['__version__'],
        description=about['__description__'],
        long_description=readme + '\n\n' + history,
        author=about['__author__'],
        author_email=about['__author_email__'],
        url=about['__url__'],
        license=about['__license__'],
        platforms=['any'],
        packages=["<redacted>"],
        package_data={'': ['LICENSE']},
        include_package_data=True,
        python_requires=">=3.7",
        install_requires=install_requires,
        tests_require=tests_requires,
        classifiers=(
            'Development Status :: 1 - Beta',
            'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: GIS',
            'Intended Audience :: Developers',
            'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
            'Natural Language :: English',
            'License :: GPLv3',
            'Operating System :: OS Independent',
            'Programming Language :: Python',
            'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7'
        )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing it in a virtual environment? I'm not exactly sure if it works or not. It's not really answering your question, but I feel it's a better solution in the long run. To set one up quickly : `python3 -m venv venv; source venv/bin/activate; pip install <myPackage>`

Comment: @MichaelRobinson Yes, I am installing it in a conda environment

Comment: Please have a look at how they do it with pyinstaller https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/

If the C compiled binaries are present in the directory, it simply uses them. Otherwise it compiles them on the users machine.
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/installation.html#installing-from-the-archive